# вывести количество чисел, которые дают сумму 4

Tags: java

Всем привет. Помогите, пожалуйста с задачей. Нужно вывести количество чисел, которые дают сумму 4
Вот код, который сделала я ,но у меня ничего не выводит а должно выводиться 4 так как `0+2+1+1=4`

```
public class Main {
    
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
 int[] arr = {0, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1};
        
int sum = 0;
        
int count = 0;
        
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            
while (sum != 4) {
                
sum = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];
            }
            
count++;
            
 System.out.println(count);
            
       }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Вы считаете не сумму с накоплением, а пересчитываете сумму текущего и следующего чисел. `sum = arr[i] + arr[i + 1];` - косяк тут.

Comment: так в массиве я задала такие числа 0, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1->0+2+1+1=4(всего первых 4 числа) поэтому выводится 4

Comment: у меня ничего не выводит

Comment: Теоретически (если нет иных косяков - смотреть лень) там должно быть нечто типа `sum += arr[i];`. A `count++;` должна быть внутри цикла.

Comment: я использовала while то есть пока сумма не будет равно нулю то  пусть одно число массива прибавляет  следующее число массива и потом считаю count сколько чисел я всего прибавила что бы была  сумма 4

Comment: пробовала уже  count++; поставить внутрь цикла .Это проблему не решила

Comment: если вариантов составления суммы числа 4 несколько, то что выводить?

Comment: просто сколько чисел дают сумму 4 Например имеем массив чисел 0, 2, 1, 1, 9, 1 и должно вывести 4 так как 0+2+1+1=4->всего первых 4 цифр делают сумму 4

Comment: Проблема в том, что во внутреннем цикле у вас никакого движения по массиву вообще нет)

Comment: в смысле нет?я использовала цикл for

Comment: внутренний цикл у вас while, он складывает 2 раза 0+2, получает 4, и на следующих итерациях цикла for вы в while вообще не попадаете.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  sum += arr[i];
  count++;
  if (sum >= 4) break;
}

if (sum == 4) {
  // ok, выводим count
} else {
  // не нашли частичную сумму 4
}
```

[Fiddle](https://onlinegdb.com/BkUfwri_D)

Comment: так тоже ничего не выводит

Comment: а все извините ,код работает .Спасибо вам большое ,сейчас буду нго анализировать

Answer (score 0):

```
    public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = {0, 2, 9, 1, 3,  1};
        int sum = 0;
        for (int j : arr) {
            if (j < 4 && sum + j <= 4) {
                sum += j;
                System.out.print(j + "+");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("=" + sum);
    }
}
```

Надо бы подопиливать, но в первом приближении так.

Comment: а вот с while эту задачу возможно решить или все таки лучше с if?

Comment: Можно, но зачем? У вас там вообще вечный цикл получался.

Comment: Спасибо вам большое за помощь